# Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration melwin

Tags: java, android

I do get this error in this line. Please help me with this.

```
public enum **Status**
    {
     CLASS_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION = new Status("CLASS_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION", 2);
     ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION = new Status("ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION", 3);
      INSTANTIATION_EXCEPTION = new Status("INSTANTIATION_EXCEPTION", 4);
      MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION = new Status("MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION", 5);
      IO_EXCEPTION = new Status("IO_EXCEPTION", 6);
      INVALID_ACTION = new Status("INVALID_ACTION", 7);
      JSON_EXCEPTION = new Status("JSON_EXCEPTION", 8);
      ERROR = new Status("ERROR", 9);



  Status[] arrayOfStatus = new Status[10];
  arrayOfStatus[0] = NO_RESULT;
  arrayOfStatus[1] = OK;
  arrayOfStatus[2] = CLASS_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION;
  arrayOfStatus[3] = ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION;
  arrayOfStatus[4] = INSTANTIATION_EXCEPTION;
  arrayOfStatus[5] = MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION;
  arrayOfStatus[6] = IO_EXCEPTION;
  arrayOfStatus[7] = INVALID_ACTION;
  arrayOfStatus[8] = JSON_EXCEPTION;
  arrayOfStatus[9] = ERROR;
  $VALUES = arrayOfStatus;


}
```

Comment: public class Enum? or maaybe you need to specify the kind of enum, like for example public String/.. Enum. but i believe that dollar$ doesn't work at java. backend.

Comment: Your code is not even close to valid Java. Please read up on Enums here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, enum in Java is implemented as a class with a list of predefined values, so it may (and must in you case) contain fields and constructors (and methods, of course).

So here is something similar to your attempt and valid Java Enum

```
enum Status {

    CLASS_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION("CLASS_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION", 2),
    ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION("ILLEGAL_ACCESS_EXCEPTION", 3),
    INSTANTIATION_EXCEPTION("INSTANTIATION_EXCEPTION", 4),
    MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION("MALFORMED_URL_EXCEPTION", 5),
    IO_EXCEPTION("IO_EXCEPTION", 6),
    INVALID_ACTION("INVALID_ACTION", 7),
    JSON_EXCEPTION("JSON_EXCEPTION", 8),
    ERROR("ERROR", 9);

    private String title;
    private int number;

    private Status(String title, int number) {
        this.title = title;
        this.number = number;
    }

    // getters
}
```

After this definition you can create array of Enum values if you really need it.